# Sign certificate request error "Expecting trusted request"

Tags: openssl, certificate

I tried to use openssl to sign cert request with my own CA. There are two options.

1. `openssl x509`.

   ```
   openssl X509 -req -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.pem -in bob.csr -out bob.crt -CAcreateserial`
   ```

Some posts say x509 is used to generate self-signed certificates.

But error occurs using `openssl X509`:

```
unable to load certificate
6612:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start       
line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

2. `openssl ca`:

   ```
   openssl ca -in bob.csr -out bob.crt -keyfile ca.key
   ```

It needs to config openssl.config beforehand. E.g., create dir `./demoCA`.

Please let me know which way is correct. If `openssl x509` is correct, how to solve `expecting trusted certificate` error? Very appreciate!

Comment: Your first command should work (and does for me) if the `-CA` file here `ca.crt` contains the CA cert; if the `-CA` file is something other than a cert I get the error you do (and if it's a cert but the wrong cert I get `0B080074 ... key values mismatch`). Check that file. `openssl ca` is a valid alternative which does need several things set in a config file, although that file can have any name you choose (with `-config`) and it doesn't have to use a specific subdirectory or even any subdirectory, that's just a convention.

Comment: I had the same message after `SSL_CTX_use_certificate` and I solved it with merging two files into one: the one with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and the one with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

Answer (score 5):

> Please let me know which way is correct. If openssl x509 is correct, how to solve expecting trusted certificate error? Very appreciate!

You use `openssl x509` to work with certificates. Since you don't have a certificate, you should not use `openssl x509`.

You use `openssl req` for signing requests. *If* you use *just* `openssl req`, then you create a signing request.

*If* you use `openssl req -x509`, then you create a self signed certificate. It forgoes the signing request and moves directly to the certificate.

If you need help becoming your own CA, then see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21297139/608639)

If you need help with signing requests and well-formed certificates, then see [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639).

Comment: `req -x509` can only create selfsigned, which is apparently not what OP wants. `x509` has several functions, among which `x509 -req -CA [-CAkey]` as the OP correctly shows can create a signed-by-CA cert.